# Animate on scroll aos library usage for custom line grow animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to use aos (animate on scoll) library of michalsnik. I am trying to create a custom animation, where a line growing animation should appear on every scrolling down. I mean just the width of a horizontal line grows from 0 to 100% when it appears on the screen while scrolling down. I configured my page's css file like this:

```
#linebottom {
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
position:relative;
}

@keyframes grow {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

And I opened the aos.css file. And added these lines:

```
[data-aos=xyz]{
      animation: grow 4s forwards;
  }
  [data-aos=xyz].aos-animate{
      animation: none;
  }
```

But the animation plays only when the page refreshes. It doesn't restart when scrolling up and down. Its width gets to 100% and stays there. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to do this using plain css, it will become very complicated. Use this approach:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding:10px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: grey;
}
.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: green;
  width: 0%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  Scroll Indicator - Scroll Down to See The Effect
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
  </div>  
</div>

<div class="content">
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablab
</div>

<script>
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Using a little bit of javascript it became much more easy. I hopy you understood the javascript code.

Comment: Thank you @Tejas for this idea and effort, but the point I'm searching is just the width of a line grows from 0 to 100% when it appears on the screen while scrolling down. In order to avoid misunderstandings, I edited my post. I didn't use javascript since I tried using aos library.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I finally know what you wanted to do, here is another approach I tried using plain CSS:

```css
.example-post {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  color: #7f8b90;
  border-top: 1px dotted #aaa;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #aaa;
}
.example-post p {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.example-post a {
  color: #607D8B;
}
.example-post:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #CDDC39 0%, #03A9F4 50%, #e6f0f5 50%);
    height: calc(100% - 100vh + 6px);
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.example-post:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: #e6f0f5;
    height: calc(100vh - 6px);
    width: 100%;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
code {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.entry-content {
    max-width: 790px;
    margin: 0 auto;  
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: calc(-100vh + 6px);
    padding: 0 15px;
}

/* demo stuff */
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #e6f0f5;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
html, button, input, select, textarea {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    color: #92a4ad;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.zoom-area { 
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 50px auto 70px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.link-container {
  text-align: center;
}
a.more-link {
      font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 10px 5px 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #416475;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #92a4ad;
}
```

```html
<h1>Reading Progress Bar CSS Only</h1>
<section class="example-post">
  <div class="entry-content">
    <h2>Example Post</h2>
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
<p>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
</div>
```

Comment: again not the point, but this is also very useful piece of code with pure css, thanks for that regarding this community. I was trying to see an extending horizontal line just when the div of that line appears on the page while scrolling down, whose length doesn't depend on the scroll amount. It just gets from 0 width to 100% width in 3 seconds when it appears on the screen. I think a css keyframe animation but just when it is seen while scrolling down. The thing I was searching was I think much more simpler than your codes:) But these are also very useful infos. Thanks bro